# How does one install a PHP library on Mac?

Tags: php

I'm using Apache/SQL/PHP via MAMP on my Mac. I have the PHP library LIB_http.php. I tried to understand how to install it, but seem unable to figure this out. Google search was useless, so was the PHP manual at php.net. Can you help?

Comment: What do you mean install it? A basic working understanding of php would allow you to use a php library in a website. What exactly have you tried/are trying to do?

Comment: from where did you get `PHP library - LIB_http.php` ? It's `.php` so most probably you should include it your project like `include_once('/path/to/lib_http.php')` or `require_once('/path/to/lib_http.php')`

Comment: http://www.webbotsspidersscreenscrapers.com/DSP_download.php

Comment: Trying to use it via "include("LIB_http.php") presumably that requires for the library to be "installed" somewhere.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but a newbie question without having some decent knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Class Library which needs to be included in your project. You can download their example scripts to learn how to use it.

You should include it your project like `include_once('/path/to/lib_http.php')` or `require_once('/path/to/lib_http.php')`

You can refer Official Docs for [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) and [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php);

Comment: their example only uses include("LIB_http.php"), not include_once or require once. I assumed there is a folder I need to copy the php library into. Am I wrong? the example in the book I should add

Comment: Please refer php docs to know the difference between include, require, include_once and require_once. Yes, you need to extract the library in your projects folder. I suggest you to learn the php basics first. :)